# Why is my glyphicon pencil fat

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

```
<h1 class="h1name" style="" ><bold><%= @user %></bold><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></h1>
```

[image: Fat glyphicon]

[image: Desired Glyphicon]

I don't know why I'm getting a fat glyphicon-pencil instead of the correct one as seen in the Bootstrap Components website. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use

```
 gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
```

Is the bootstrap version I'm using on my ruby on rails project

I am using roboto for fonts

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Another Sample with the envelope glyphicon

[image: fat envelope]

[image: correct envelope]

without the roboto font it looks like this (still very different from the desired one)
[image]

Comment: Try using another icon instead of pencil and see if you face the same issue?

Comment: Check the icon fonts are referenced correctly?

Comment: Try giving font-size explicitly for the font icon. ie, .glyphicon-pencil{ font-size: 10px; }  just a suggestion.

Comment: adding the font size did not work :(

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by checking if the fonts are referenced correctly?

Comment: give the link that you are using for font icon

Comment: If you inspect the span that has class "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil", do the developer tools show that it has font-family 'Glyphicons Halflings'?

Also, are the fonts loading correctly? Check for 404 errors in the developer tools Network panel after reloading the page with the developer tools open.

Comment: can you please check font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem, I tried by replacing the local file with cdn path. And it works.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional: Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Optional: Incorporate the Bootstrap JavaScript plugins -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```